# Send a slack notification every time Log::error is triggered

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5, I want to be notified (on slack but it does not matter) every time `Log::error` (or similar) is triggered, by a direct call to this method or by the default `ExceptionHandler` calling `report` method. I think I have to extends default Laravel's Log system but I'm not sure. **What's the (best) "laravel way" to do this ?** (without changing every `Log::error` calls in my whole code).

First, I thought I only have to change Log Facade to one other but it will not handle the `ExceptionHandler` (i.e. on 500 errors due to uncaught Exception). One other solution could be add some code directly in the `ExceptionHandler`, but it will not be triggered if I report an error by `Log::error()` or some other way (`app('logger')->error()`, `logger()->error()`, etc.).

Comment: You can look at using the Slack monolog handler, it will be automatically in your dependancies, you just need to set it up https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/SlackHandler.php

This is a small guide that should help http://www.sitepoint.com/logging-with-monolog-from-devtools-to-slack/#slack-handler

This method is probably better than using the Laravel Log event as it's less framework agnostic and the message logging might not work with early on errors thrown in the Laravel framework

Comment: I actually just found a use for this in my own project so I went through and set it up.  I've detailed exactly what I've done in an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Edit: Broken as of Laravel 5.6**

The `Log` facade is really just a wrapper for an underlying instance of `Monolog`.  The good news is Monolog comes with support for Slack.  You just need to tell Monolog to use it.

With that said, everything can be setup in 3 lines of code.

```
$monolog = \Log::getMonolog();
$slackHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\SlackHandler('your-token', '#your-channel', 'Monolog', true, null, \Monolog\Logger::ERROR);
$monolog->pushHandler($slackHandler);
```

Then to get this running, you can either create your own service provider for it or just drop it in `AppServiceProvider`'s `boot` method.

You may want to look at the source code for `SlackHandler` just in case there are more options the constructor takes which you would need to use.

Now whenever you `\Log::error('some error');`, that error's message will be sent to the Slack channel you have setup.  Please note this "bubbles up" which means it will be sent to the Slack channel for any logging done error and up, `error`, `critical`, `alert`, and `emergency`.  Set the `bubble` parameter to `false` if you only want it to log `error`s.

Comment: Many thanks, it really helps! I've just created a laravel provider on gihub thanks to you. Can I credit you? (nickname or user3158900)?

Comment: @rap-2-h I'd love to see the link to the Github page because I want to do this same error handling (and trigger an IFTTT event in addition to Slack).

Comment: Monolog now also has an easier to use "SlackWebhookHandler" which uses Slack webhooks.  Their "SlackHandler" uses Slack oauth tokens which are a little trickier to get and set up.

Answer (score 15):

**For Laravel 5.6 and above:**

Laravel suppports slack driver for logging beginning with 5.6. Configure your slack channel in `config/logging.php` like so:

```
'slack' => [
    'driver' => 'slack',
    'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
    'username' => 'Laravel Log',
    'emoji' => ':boom:',
    'level' => 'critical',
],
```

Now all the log messages which have an importance critical or above will automatically logged to slack channel.

**You can also log to slack channel specifically:**

```
Log::channel('slack')->info('Something happened!');
```

More info in [Laravel logging](https://laravel.com/docs/logging) and [Slack incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks).

Comment: concerning env vars, laravel recommends tu use config instead. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration

Comment: @bigcat Not when you are using them to actually define config.  This is referencing the env in Laravel by default.

Comment: It will deprecated. "Please note, this is a legacy custom integration - an outdated way for teams to integrate with Slack. These integrations lack newer features and they will be deprecated and possibly removed in the future. We do not recommend their use. Instead, we suggest that you check out their replacement: Slack apps."

Answer (score 7):

You can listen to `illuminate.log [String $level, String $message, Array $context]` event. If `$level` equals `error`, you will send notification.

Define event listener in your `EventServiceProvider`

```
protected $listen = [
    'illuminate.log' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogEventListener'
    ]
];
```

This will tell Laravel to fire `LogEventListener` when `illuminate.log` event is fired.

Then create this listener:

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class LogEventListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  DeployDisabledEvent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle($event)
    {
        if ($event->type == 'error') {
            $this->notifyViaSlack($event->message, $event->context);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send Slack notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $message
     * @param  string  $context
     * @return void
     */
    protected function notifyViaSlack($message, $context)
    {
        /*
         * Slack notification logic
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Not sure to know how to do this... Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @rap-2-h I improved my answer with an example, now it should be clear enough :)

Comment: In version 5.1 the first parameter passed to the handler appears to be a string representing the log level, not the array.

Comment: Very helpful, this is a nice way to get the things done :), thanks